# Determine raster image file type based on content

Tags: c#, raster, file-type

I have hundreds of thousands raster (scanned) image files, all saved without a file extension.  The files are in various formats (.jpg, .bmp, .tif, .png, .pdf, .gif ...etc.).   I need to find all the .tif files without reading the entire contents of each file.  Excluding some types is easy, e.g. open a file, read the first line, exclude if it contains "PDF".  However, because I do not have an exhaustive list of possible file types I need to positively identify .tif files. Can this be done using C#?

Comment: **[The TIFF File Format](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm)**

Comment: Excellent, thanks -  @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp would it be safe to assume that if the first two characters are II or MM that the file is positively a .tif, or could other raster formats also start with those characters?

Comment: The company I work for has an imaging SDK that's particularly strong in the area of [file formats](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/formats). It supports dozens of raster image formats (hundreds if you count file sub-types). There's a simple [C# tutorial](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/tutorials/dotnet-console-extract-image-information.html) that shows how to get the type of file using the LEADTOOLS SDK. One function call is needed, which is `RasterCodecs.GetInformation()`. There's a [free evaluation here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).

Comment: Thanks Amin. I'm actually a LEADTOOLS customer already and hadn't noticed that feature so this tip is handy.